# Unable to send JSON object as request parameter as JSON.stringify gives circular reference error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a tree, to be displayed on the screen, which is basically a JSON object. I want to send this JSON object to the Java class as a `request` parameter.

Following is a sample of the JSON object:

```
// Root node
var rootNode = { Content: "Root", Nodes:[] };
// First Level
rootNode.Nodes[0] = { Content: "Employee Code", navigationType: "0"};
rootNode.Nodes[1] = { Content: "Problem Area", navigationType: "1" };
// Second Level
rootNode.Nodes[1].Nodes = [{ Content : "ACC-HO", Collapsed: true},
                           { Content : "ACC-SALES" },
                           { Content : "BUSI. HEAD", ToolTip: "Click ME!" },
                           { Content : "CEO"}
                          ];
```

Now the plugin, which creates this tree out of the JSON object, stores the reference of the `Parent` Node in each of the nodes. Hence this results in a `circular reference` where a node stores reference of its children and each child node stores the reference of its Parent

Due to this I am [unable to use JSON.stringify(rootNode)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/cc836474%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I want to send the `rootNode` object as a request parameter using Ajax. I have done the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "treeDemo_!saveTree",
            data: {treeObject: JSON.stringify(rootNode) },
            success : function(resp) {      
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

But as I mentioned, JSON.stringify doesnt work in my case. So can anyone suggest an alternative way to send the JSON object as a request parameter which I can receive in the Java code and process further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution, if you can't clean the plugin, is to clone the rootNode object and in the process don't copy the 'Parent' property :

```
function goclone(source) {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(source) === '[object Array]') {
        var clone = [];
        for (var i=0; i<source.length; i++) {
            clone[i] = goclone(source[i]);
        }
        return clone;
    } else if (typeof(source)=="object") {
        var clone = {};
        for (var prop in source) {
            if (source.hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop!='Parent') {
                clone[prop] = goclone(source[prop]);
            }
        }
        return clone;
    } else {
        return source;
    }
}

var serializableRootNode = goclone(rootNode);
```

The `serializableRootNode` doesn't contain the 'Parent' properties.

Adapt the code if the parent reference isn't called exactly 'Parent'.

Comment: You are suggesting to change the actual object by removing the reference to the Parents. But what if I dont want to change actual object and pass it as it is to the Java class. I will require the Parent reference in each node even in the Java class. Any workaround?

Comment: Why send the parent reference ? This would imply defining a special code to describe it and it's just overhead : you can very easily reconstruct it in java. A general rule is to avoid circular structures and when you can't avoid them (which is very very rare), use a different (not redundant) structure for all kind of persistance.

Comment: Thank you @dystroy! This method is working perfectly fine. But can I ask for one more thing. What if want to remove few more attributes just like `Parent` from the rootNode and keep only those required for my use? I tried adding one more `else if` condition in the same method having appropriate property name. But it gave a `stack overflow` error at `clone[prop] = goclone(source[prop]);`

Comment: If you have only 3 or 4 more possible attributes, you may simply add a few `&& prop!='someAttr'` in the existing test. Beware that if you follow a cyclic link, the cloning also lead to a stack overflow (you can't clone a cyclic structure using this).

Comment: excellent! it worked. I was trying `else if`, `|| prop!='someAttr'` thinking it will loop over each property and hence it did not work. Thank you very much!